# Determinar uma quantia de tempo para responder algo em Batch

Tags: cmd, batch

É possível determinar uma quantia de tempo para que o usuário responda uma questão em um batch? Se eu fosse usar um batch para desligar o computador, o usuário teria 1 minuto para responder algo naquele batch, se não fazer nada, o comando se anula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer isso.

Crie um arquivo com os seguintes comandos:

```
@echo off
rem Programado o desligamento em 2 minutos (120 segundos)
shutdown -s -t 120
rem Esperando entrada do usuário, se não digitar nada não cancela o desligamento.
:verifica
echo Digite algo:
set /p "info="
rem Verificar se digitou alguma informação ou apenas deu enter.
IF "%info%"=="" (
    rem Se não digitou nada volta a pedir para digitar algo.
    goto verifica
) else (
    rem Cancela desligamento.
    shutdown -a
    echo Desligamento cancelado!
)
pause > nul
```

> Caso pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd> sem digitar nada o comando de desligamento não será cancelado.